# Dynamically put contenteditable based on specific value

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Im trying to put `contenteditable` based on the value of `term`, Example, If the value of term is `"Prelim"` the row prelim will be editable and the rest is not editable. But the problem to my solution is, there are no data displayed but the `row number` is correct and the `expected row` to be `editable` is editable. It's just blank. Can someone help me to find what's the cause of this?

output of my code:
[image]
Here's the code. **I just put the important code here** I did not put the other code because i think the one causing problem is the way of my **if else statement**.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM encode";
    $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
      $term = $row['term'];
    }
    $output .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['middlename'].'</td>';
                if($term == "Prelim"){
                $output .= '<td class="prelim" data-id1="'.$row['grade_id'].'" contenteditable>'.$row['prelim_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                $output .= '<td class="prelim" data-id1="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['prelim_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                if($term == "Midterm"){
                $output .= '<td class="midterm" data-id2="'.$row['grade_id'].'" contenteditable>'.$row['midterm_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                  $output .= '<td class="midterm" data-id2="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['midterm_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                if($term == "Finals"){
                  $output .= '<td class="finals" data-id3="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['finals_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                  $output .= '<td class="finals" data-id3="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['finals_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                if($term == "Final Grade"){
                  $output .= ' <td class="final" data-id4="'.$row['grade_id'].'" contenteditable>'.$row['final_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                  $output .= ' <td class="final" data-id4="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['final_grade'].'</td>';
                }
              $output .=' </tr>';
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. You have used the variable `$row` in the wrong way. First you assign `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` in the outer while loop. Then again you assign to the same variable `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)` in the inner while loop.

The values you expect to get are in the `$results` variable. But your current assignment (which happen in the inner while loop) make your `$row` variable's value to be overridden by a row in `$result`. All you have to do is just use two variables to access rows in those 2 queries.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM encode";
    $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    while($otherRow = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
      $term = $otherRow['term'];
    }
    // Your existing code
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.